# Python stops reading .py script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script in a ".py" file, which consists basically in something like this:

```
#import time and tcmodule.py module
import time
import tcmodule as tc

# Set Inputs (step 1):
tc.SetInput1(0)
tc.SetInput2(0)
tc.SetInput3(0)
time.sleep(0.250)
print(time.time())

# Set Inputs (step 2):
tc.SetInput1(3)
tc.SetInput2(6)
tc.SetInput3(12)
time.sleep(0.250)
print(time.time())

#the code continues the same way...
```

The "Set Inputs" block containing those 4 instructions is repeated approximately 900 times, so the file is quite long but simple to understand. It just gives some values to some variables and waits for 250ms.

The problem is that while I am executing the program, pythonwin suddenly stops reading the script (I know that because suddenly it stops printing the time) and I don´t know why that happens. The most strange thing is that it stops at a diferrent place every time, so I guess the code is ok. Does anybody know what is the problem with the code?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't implement the repeated code with a loop?

Comment: I hope you repeat the 900 times in a loop and not by hand?? Have you tried making the sleep time longer?

Comment: 5K lines is not that much. Have you tried to run it without `pythonwin` using plain `python` executable?

Comment: Did you typo and instead of `sleep(0.250)` have `sleep(0250)` or similar?

Comment: I cannot implement it with a loop since the value of each input parameter comes from a trace from another program, and I just parse the traces to create this file. I mean, the values may change in any way, is not just incrasing or decreasing the values regularly every 250ms.

Comment: @Iban you could use the output from the other program to generate a list of tuples, and then just have a loop that goes over the list.

Comment: @Amber Can you give me a brief example of how to create a list of tuples? I think it would be more elegant and maybe it fixes the problem.

Comment: You said you generate the .py file.  Are you running this .py file inside a script?  if so How are you calling it?

Comment: @Back2Basics Yes, I run the py file from another script, by typing #import tc_script  (tc_script.py is the name of the file) Is that problematic?

Comment: Turn outs there isn't a timeout on loading modules (if one gets caught in an infinite loop then it should keep going.)

Comment: @poke already did below, Iban.

Answer (score 0):

You really should restructure your program so you do *not* need to repeat yourself that often. Even if the parameters to the `SetInput` calls are different each time, you can still save a lot:

```
import time
import tcmodule as tc

inputs = [
    (0, 0, 0),
    (3, 6, 12),
    # more values here
]

for a, b, c in inputs:
    tc.SetInput1(a)
    tc.SetInput2(b)
    tc.SetInput3(c)
    time.sleep(0.250)
    print(time.time())
```

You essentially need to store all your input parameters in a big list and specify that once; then you loop over the values and just write the block where you call those functions *once*. This will also prevent that you have any typing errors in calls somewhere deep in the file. So maybe this already fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a problem with a typo somewhere in your 900 iterations. I suggest you do something like this. It will make it much easier to debug.

```
# create a list of lists
# each sublist will contain the three values that go with each SetInput function
# add as many sublists as necessary 
inputs = [[0, 0, 0], [3, 6, 12]]

for inp in inputs:
    print "step", inp
    tc.SetInput1(inp[0])
    tc.SetInput2(inp[1])
    tc.SetInput3(inp[2])
    time.sleep(0.250)
    print(time.time())
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a memory profiler in this.  You could be running out of memory.  Or the inputs could be different than tc.SetInput's are expecting.

```
#import time and tcmodule.py module
import time
import tcmodule as tc
from memory_profiler import profile

@profile
def my_func():
    tc.SetInput1(input1)
    tc.SetInput2(input2)
    tc.SetInput3(input3)
    time.sleep(0250)
    print(time.time())
def parseline():
   #take out the "pass" and return the 3 input values
   pass

with somefile.txt as txtfile:
   for line in file:
      try:
          input1,input2,input3=parseline(line)
          myfunc(input1,input2,input3)
      except Exception:
          #add error handling here and change the Exception.
```